# Pandas Multiindex selection criteria alongwith column selection criteria

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need to query a Pandas Dataframe based on multiple criteria on the Index and the Column. Please have a look at my data below. 'Country' and 'Surname' are two separate indices, while 'Name', 'Score', 'Type' are columns.

```
y = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Nikhil', 'Ankit', 'Keval', 'Darpan', 'Rajesh', 'John', 'Lynda'],
                  'Score':[89,92,96,82,95,98,97], 
                  'Type':['Fat','Slim','Fat','Slim','Fat','Slim','Slim'],
                  'Country':['India','USA','Denmark','Australia','Italy','China','Israel'],
                  'Surname':['Sharma','Sharma','Patel','Shah','Sharma','Sharma','Sharma']}                 
                ).set_index('Country').set_index('Surname', append=True)
```

[image]

I want to select data which meets following criteria:

- Country should neither be India nor be USA
- Surname should be Sharma
- Score should be equal to or above 90
- Type should be Slim

Comment: Kindly share data not pics

Comment: @sammywemmy - he did share the data. Not all data is easily copy-pasteable..

Comment: Added data so that it can be reproduced

Answer (score 2):

For select in columns or in MultiIndex levels is possible use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?query-use-cases#the-query-method) with chained masks by `and` or `&`:

```
q='Country not in ["India","USA"] and Surname == "Sharma" and Score >= 90 and Type == "Slim"'
```

Or:

```
q = 'Country not in ["India","USA"] & Surname == "Sharma" & Score >= 90 & Type == "Slim"'
```

---

```
print (y.query(q))
                  Name  Score  Type
Country Surname                    
China   Sharma    John     98  Slim
Israel  Sharma   Lynda     97  Slim
```

Alternative with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), but chaining masks is strictly `&`:

```
m1 = ~y.index.get_level_values('Country').isin(["India","USA"])
m2 = y.index.get_level_values('Surname') == 'Sharma'
m3 = y['Score'].ge(90)
m4 = y['Type'].eq('Slim')
print (y[m1 & m2 & m3 & m4])
                  Name  Score  Type
Country Surname                    
China   Sharma    John     98  Slim
Israel  Sharma   Lynda     97  Slim
```

Comment: A pedagogical question here, can you combine all for of those conditions?

Comment: @ScottBoston - I guess in query yes, by `or` or `|` or by `and` or `&`

Comment: So i combined your query into one, and it is not giving me correct result. 'code'df.query( ('Country not in ["India","USA"]') and ('Surname == "Sharma"') and ('Score >= 90') and ('Type == "Slim"')  ) 'code'

Comment: So, ie, like this? `print (y.query('Country not in ["India","USA"] and Surname == "Sharma"'))`

Comment: @quietboy I do get the correct result by doing this `y.query('Country not in ["India","USA"] and Surname == "Sharma" and Score >= 90 and Type =="Slim"')`

Comment: @ScottBoston - yes, that does. Looks my brackets are causing an issue in the query

Comment: @ScottBoston - oops, I done understand your suggestion, but now yes, edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
df.loc[(~df.index.isin(['India', 'USA'], level='Country'))& (df.index.get_level_values('Surname') == 'Sharma') & (df['Score'] >= 90) & (df['Type'] == 'Slim')]
```